# Getting a debugmanifest error at runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have imported an android project into Android studio ( I am a first time user of android studio.. was previously working on eclipse). So when building the project I get no errors. When running the code, however, I am getting the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87
```

I make use of **google maps** and hence I require the **google play services**. This project was working fine in eclipse, but not here in Android studio. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like you have a little problem with your manifest file. You should try just change minSdkVersion from 8 to 9. Hope it'll help.

Comment: That's the first thing I did... it just ignores the changes I made.. so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up your build.gradle(module:app) in android studio..

In android studio minSdkVersion is not to be put in android manifest but in gradle..
for explanation see [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res)

look's like you need to declare again you Google Play Service in gradle since you move the app from eclipse, see this for more explanation [Adding libraries without resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issues. The Google Play SDK was probably updated when you migrated to Android Studio and Grade. As far as I understand the latest Google Play Services requires at least version 9 for debugging.

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
>
> A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
>
> ...

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html