# Changing Minimum SDK to 19 creating Build Error messages

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Project is working fine and not gerenating any error message when Minimum SDK is set to `21`, but this Error message occurs when i set it to `19`.

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processArmeabi-v7aDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> ```

I am sharing my `gradle` and `Manifest` file, Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

**Project Level build gradle File.**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'  
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**App Level Build Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'

            universalApk true
        }
}


  compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId com.myapp.app
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}



dependencies {


    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
}
```

**Android Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.App.MyApp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<!-- GCM Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsSampleApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name=".application.services.LogoutService" />

    <!-- GCM RECEIVER -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.App.MyApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service
        android:name=".GoogleCloudMessaging.GcmService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- GCM RECEIVER -->

    <activity
        android:name=".MyAppMainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SplashDefaultActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashDefaultActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashVideoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VideosListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_videos_list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_video"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".application.activities.taskMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/task_map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".application.activities.checkout.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/checkout_login_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".application.activities.SectionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/section_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".application.activities.streetFullScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_full_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".application.activities.streetFullScreenSectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_full_screen_section"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".gameActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_day"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyAppMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SplashDefaultActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".taskViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_view"
        android:parentActivityName=".gameActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.App.MyApp.gameActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TeamActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_team"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyAppMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SplashDefaultActivity" />
    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name=".LegalActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".game.SimplestreetViewerActivity" />         
    <activity android:name=".game.insiderActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".CoachesBioActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TeamStandingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_team_standings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebViews.Slider_News_View"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_news__web__views"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebViews.MyAppGear"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_MyApp_gear"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".videonPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name=".LollipopVideoListActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MyAppPromotionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_MyApp_promotion"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        ></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Error Log**

```
2016-09-29 18:03:52,218 [79526482]   WARN - .tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo - getMergedManifest failed Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs 
2016-09-29 18:04:04,174 [79538438]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2016-09-29 18:04:28,192 [79562456]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 0ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-09-29 18:04:28,266 [79562530]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 74ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-09-29 18:04:29,657 [79563921]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2016-09-29 18:04:31,543 [79565807]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - High memory usage (free 200 of 1246 MB) while dumping threads to C:\Users\taha\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\log\threadDumps-20160928-195850-AI-145.3276617\20160929-180431\threadDump-20160929-180431.txt 
2016-09-29 18:04:39,732 [79573996]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-09-29 18:04:40,045 [79574309]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 313ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-09-29 18:04:40,045 [79574309]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 10932 files to update 
2016-09-29 18:04:47,545 [79581809]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 7500ms; general responsiveness: 0/24 sluggish, 17/24 very slow; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-09-29 18:04:47,846 [79582110]   WARN - .tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo - getMergedManifest failed Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs 
2016-09-29 18:04:48,529 [79582793]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2016-09-29 18:04:48,529 [79582793]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput
```

Comment: *... with multiple errors, see logs* ... you see, it would be helpful to see the logs

Comment: its showing nothing on Android Monitor

Comment: *its showing nothing on Android Monitor* ... obviously ... it is build/compile time error check EventLog or Gradle Console

Comment: 1) Please show the entire manifest 2) Make sure all the  Google play services versions are the same

Comment: @cricket_007: I have added my manifest file, I  don;t understand why its not working on Kitkat, when the same thing is working on lollipop.

Comment: Well, the error says "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs", which is why I asked for the whole manifest. Not sure what to look for, but are the no more error logs as the output says there are?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the error log

Comment: @Selvin : I have added the error log

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'` 3 different gms versions?

Comment: Not seeing any error there, just warn and info

Comment: Yeah, this post hints at a problem with the Google play services. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660391/getting-a-debugmanifest-error-at-runtime

Comment: Yes, there are no errors in Manifest file. I am looking into the provided link. Thanks